# How can I find video tags using the Youtube Data API (v3)?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube Data API (V3, PHP), how can I find video tags using this?

(Note: Video page source showing *og:video:tag.*)

Answer (score 0):

With v3 you can only view tags in the video snippet if you are the video owner. For non-owners, you can always parse the meta keywords field for tags in the video page source.